# How to make a US map based on state-level data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use ggplot2 to make a US map based on some state level data, and color each state based on the value of one variable.

```
State   loan
AL      25310770
AK      45310770
AZ      35310770
AR      25682770
   ...
```

Edit: Thanks to @Hector Haffenden, the `dput(head(your_data))` gives:

```
structure(list(state = c("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "IL", "MA"), 
     loan = c(25310770, 21230922, 15055436, 15212963, 12796921, 20311736), 
     row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Since I have a variable of state name, is it possible to automatically match each row to the map based on the state name abbreviations? Here is an example of my expected output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4HcL.png

Comment: Hello "The R", your question was well written. A potential improvement could be adding the results from `dput(head(your_data))` to the question. This allows someone to copy paste a sample. Will get you a much faster and more accurate answer :) Thanks for the accept and welcome to stack.

Comment: @HectorHaffenden Thanks for your advice! I will do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, first define our data like this,

```
dat <- data.frame(state = c("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR"), Loan = c(25310770, 45310770, 35310770, 25682770))
```

Import the packages `usmap` and `ggplot2`, then, with more complete data, it will fill the whole map, but using the sample provided, we see

```
library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)

plot_usmap(
  data = dat, values = "Loan", lines = "red"
) + 
  scale_fill_continuous(
    low = "white", high = "red", name = "Loan", label = scales::comma
  ) + 
  labs(title = "US States", subtitle = "States and loan data") +
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```

Note some states are grey due to small sample of data provided.

[image: the map]